# is there a way to download / or simulate old browsers IE6 or ios3?

Tags: internet-explorer, browser

I am in the process of writing code that will alert the user that their browser is not supported , instead of the site just looking like a complete mess.  I can not download IE6 because I already have newer version installed .  Is there a way to download or simulate old browsers to at least get a chance to see what my code will look like when it gets rendered

Comment: Have you tried [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) or [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/browsershots/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft offer [some VM images](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575) with old version of IE. Going all the way back to ie6.

Answer (score 1):

For IE6 try [IETester](http://my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).  This tool is a bit buggy but with your specific use case it should be helpful.

Another alternative would be to install a virtual machine with XP.